# Using real time data with Azure machine learning studio?

Tags: azure, machine-learning, dataset

I’ve started experimenting with the Azure ML studio and started playing with templates, upload data into it and immediately start working with it.

The problem is, I can’t seem to figure out how to tie these algorithm to real time data. Can I define a data source to input or can I configure the Azure ML studio in a way that it runs on data that I’ve specified?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Azure ML studio is for experimenting to find a proper solution to the problem set you have. You can upload data to sample, split and train your algorithms to obtain “trained models”. Once you feel comfortable with the results, you can turn that “training experiment” to a “Predictive Experiment”. From there on, your experiment will not be training but be predicting results based on user input.

To do so, you can publish the experiment as a web service, once you’ve published the web service, under the web services tab you can find your web service and run samples with it. There’s a manual input box dialog ( entry boxes here depend on the features you were using in your data samples), some documentation and REST API info for single query and BATCH query processing with the web service. Under batch you can even find sample code to connect to the published webservice.
From here on from any platform that can talk REST API, you can call the published webservice and get the results.
Find below the article about converting from training to predictive experiments
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/machine-learning-walkthrough-5-publish-web-service/

Hope this helps!